# mysql foreign key insert

Tags: mysql, key

Using this two tables i'm trying to create a query to insert a new course, but i'm using a foreign key and I don't know how to pass that users(table) id into courses(table) id.

I'm trying to get something like this

I'm completely lost, on how to insert data into a table that contains a foreign key,
what i'm trying to do is:

1. first a person can register(user table)

2.Then the user will be available to add courses ( im using the foreign key to identify the courses for a specific user)

**Users table**

```
id | username |
---------------
1  | test     |
```

**Courses table**

```
coursesid | coursesname | id(same id that in users table)

1         | courses test| 1
```

The Create Table commands are

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;



CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `courseid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coursename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (`courseid`)
FOREIGN KEY (od) REFERENCES users(id)
)
```

Comment: Insert the data into users and then into course, preferably in the same transaction.

Comment: I cannt doint at same time, because the user will be available to add as many courses as he wants

Comment: Then please explain what you need and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery for find user id, e.g.:

```
insert into course
(courseid, coursename, id)
values
(1, 'test courses',
    (SELECT id FROM users where username = 'test')
)
;
```

Of cause, if you know user id, you can insert directly this id:

```
insert into course
(courseid, coursename, id)
values
(1, 'test courses', 1)
;
```

Additional query for insert just last user id:

```
insert into course
(courseid, coursename, id)
values
(1, 'test courses',
    (SELECT max(id) FROM users)
)
;
```

Comment: "INSERT INTO courses (courseid, coursename, id) VALUES (:courseid, :coursename, (SELECT id from users where username = (select username from users))"; 

Asuming that i don't know the user name i want to query to identify the username, any ideas why is not working

Comment: But what do you know about user during course creation? Do you want insert any user, for example, last stored user? Does your system keep logged user name?

Comment: lets say that a user will login, and will be available to add a course if he is not login will not be available to added

Comment: Could you validate this by ui & programm code and prevent query execution for non-authenticated user?