# How to insert values into two tables with a foreign key relationship on mySql

Tags: mysql, workbench

npas

```
+-----+------+---------------------------+
| id  | npa  | town                      |
+-----+------+---------------------------+
|   1 |  104 |  Villars-le-terroir       |
+-----+------+---------------------------+
```

customers

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+--------+
| id | lastname | firstname | address                | phone         | email                     | mobile        | npa_id |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+--------+
|  1 | Gentizon | Alain     | Derrière le Chateaux 6 | 021 000 00 00 | xxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxx.com | 077 000 00 00 |     96 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+--------+


INSERT INTO customers (lastname,firstname,address,email,mobile) 
VALUES ('xycyxc', 'xcyc', 'xycyxc', 'xycyxcy', 'xycyxc');


INSERT INTO npas (npa,town) 
VALUES ('xycyxcy', 'xycyxc')
```

What should I do?

I am so sorry if my question is duplicate with other. I am fresher in SQL. Thanks for any help

Comment: What should I do? - publish full table definitions (we shouldn't have to assume where the FK is or on what), if you have an error publish it in full.

Comment: Use `INSERT .. SELECT` for insertion into `customers`

Comment: how i have to fill the values of customers table ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql foreign key insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035887/mysql-foreign-key-insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO npas (npa, town) 
    VALUES ('npa', 'town');

INSERT INTO customers (lastname, firstname, address, email, mobile, npa_id) 
    SELECT 'lastname', 'firstname', 'address', 'email', 'mobile', npas.id
    FROM npas
    WHERE npas.npa = 'npa' AND npas.town = 'town';
```

Comment: how i have to fill the values of customers table ?

Comment: @el_helo ?? second query do this.

Comment: hi again can you show me the trigger please !

Comment: and i am usig python to make query so i need correct way